# Error when displaying XML as text, with user selected parameters

Tags: sql, apache, parameters, birt

In my report (BIRT 4.2) I am getting data from a SQL 2008 R2 data base.  The client has asked to add a new field to the report.  The field has xml data that is formatted as text (example data below).  I can display it fine, in html, or Excel; BUT if I have a user selected parameter the report crashes (error message below).    Works fine in previews (report & SQL).
I don’t think there is any xml as text in the sample data base, so not seeing how I can create an example using the sample data.

Having string parameters is fine, but as soon as I put the ‘?’ it crashes on deploy via Apache.  The parameter is a date.

```
Works ; where OCMQM1.SUBMIT_DATE >= '2013-12-01'
Fails ; where OCMQM1.SUBMIT_DATE >= ?
```

I have tried casting the field varchar (1), etc  no matter how many characters, or what allowable format I cast to, I get the same error.  Even converting the xml to a single character of varchar and then replacing the character with a blank space in at the SQL give the same crash on deploy.  I have recreated the report from scratch and modified the existing working report, with identical results.

```
, replace (
    cast (OCMQM1.SVC_OPTIONS as varchar (1) ) 
    , '<' , ' ' 
    ) as 'Request_Details'
```

Error message

```
The following items have errors: 

Table (id = 1293): 
+ Cannot execute the statement.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet  object.
SQL error #1:The value is not set for the parameter number 1.
;
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1. (Element ID:1293)
```

XML data example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><form><text id="ExistingServerName" label="Server Name:" multiline="false" readonly="false">WINHPLNSPRD128</text><text id="ProjectFunding" label="How is this project funded?" button="4001" multiline="false" readonly="false">34542 - Enable HealthPlaNET Architecture to Support Multiple Customers</text><text id="ImplementationDate" label="Requested Implementation Date:" multiline="false" readonly="false">12/12/2013 00:00:00</text><text id="CPUNeeded" label="Additinal CPU Needed:" multiline="false" readonly="false">1</text><text id="MemoryNeeded" label="Additional Memory Needed (in GB):" multiline="false" readonly="false">0</text><text id="AdditionalStorage" label="How much additional disk storage is needed (in GB)?" multiline="false" readonly="false">0</text><text id="ExpandDrive" label="If this request is to expand an existing drive, what drive letter should be expanded?" multiline="false" readonly="false"></text></form>
```

**Note** The user supplied parameters work fine, when the xml is not part of the report.  Adding the field to the SQL, even if not added to the report table, and regardless of placement in the SQL causes the error.

Comment: As you describe this problem it looks like an encoding issue with the XML field content, in particular with question marks <? ... ?> which might be confused with query parameters. You should try to encode this field text in the query, and decode it in a birt computed column.

Comment: @dom that is what I thought at the beginning, but I would think the cast replace would have cured it.

Comment: It might be a JDBC bug. Could you try to use a stored procedure with your input parameter, rather than a direct SQL query? It could solve the problem, and at least it will clearly highlight if the bug is in BIRT or SQL server.

Comment: @dom I also have the question posted [here](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31280-error-when-displaying-xml-as-text-with-user-selected-parameters/) where it has been suggested it might be a issue with the JDBC driver. I working on getting a non-production environment to test differing JDBC solutions.